# What is the command used to associated the work-item while check-in your code in TFVC for TFS 2017?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to write a PowerShell script which help developer to check-in their changes via PowerShell ISE and link the changeset to work item. I have TFS 2017 and TVFC is configured.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be dont through `tc vc` commands, but since PowerShell can load the TFS Client Object Model, it's easy to use that to set some properties on the pending changes. You can use the VersionControlServer class to access the WorkSpace and associate the workitems using the WorkspaceCheckinParameters.AssociatedWorkItems class.

```
var checkinParameters = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(changes, comment)
{
    AssociatedWorkItems = ... <- Associate your work items here
};

return _workspace.CheckIn(checkinParameters);
```